# Retrieve media Entry comments kaltura

Tags: kaltura

Basically what the title says.

I can't find a relative service to their [api](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/). I have tried many ways but nothing worked so far. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CuePoint` service with `List` action and filter with `KalturaCuePointFilter` property `EntryIdEqual` - put entry's ID, which comments you want to recieve, and you will get list of all comments belonging to that entry.